# Does the Python interpreter bind instances to methods or the self parameter?

Tags: python, oop, methods, instance

I am reading a book about Object-Oriented Programming in Python. There is a sentence that I am confused by:

> The interpreter automatically binds the instance upon which the method is invoked to the `self` parameter.

In this sentence what is bound to the instance. the method, or the `self` parameter?

Comment: The method is bound to the instance. The instance is _self_, which is passed silently when the method is invoked e.g. `obj.method(arg)`. Method definition would look like `def method(self, arg):`. When calling it, you only have to provide `arg`, `self` is automatically bound to `obj`.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you. Can I re-write this sentence : "The interpreter automatically binds the instance upon the method which is invoked to the *self* parameter." Is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Rewrite it to what? I was trying to explain what it means (was I successful?). As an answer to the (edited) question, the method is bound to the instance via the `self` parameter.

Comment: @jesse yes this sentence is true, why do you want to re-write it ?

Comment: @alfasin Perhpas because it is hard for him to understand in its current format?

Comment: @CristiFati   Yes, I understand your meaning. I want know more about  whether the sentence that I edit  has the same meaning with the original sentence in my question.

Comment: The general idea is that the 2 entities _method_ and _instance_ are bound together (doesn't matter much which to which), and the mean to achieve that, is the `self` parameter.

Comment: @algerbrex  you got me. My English is not perfect, so the original sentence is kind difficult to understand to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not such a bad question and I'm not sure why it got downvoted so quickly...

Even though Python supports object-oriented, I find it to be much closer to functional-programming languages, one of the reasons for that is that functions are invoked "on" objects, not "by" them.

For example: `len(obj)` where in a "true" object oriented programing language you'd expect to be able to do something like `obj.length()`

In regards to the `self` parameter, you're calling `obj.method(other_args)` but what really happens under the hood is a translation of this call to: `method(obj, other_args)` you can see that when the method is declared you're doing it with the `self` variable passed in as the first argument:

```
class ...

    def method(self, other_args):
    ...
```

so it's basically all about the "translation" of `obj.method(other_args)` to `method(obj, other_args)`

Comment: _"This is actually not such a bad question so I'm not sure why it got downvoted so quickly"_ - My thoughts exactly. Not sure why some people are so down-vote happy...